# How to check if imageView fits layout or not?

Tags: android, android-layout, scale, android-imageview

I've got RelativeLayout, that has 3 Relative Relayouts inside. Second level Relative layout has imageView that is downloaded and may be in different size (height, width). I want to check if imageView fits my layout.

My second level Relative layout looks like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/tv_show_image_layout"
    android:layout_width="400dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/tvshow_imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="matrix"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/dummy" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

1) If image is too small, I need to scale him to fit layout height

2) If image is same size as layout, It's ok.

3) If image is too big, I need to add animation to slowly move up and down

For moving animation I use this code and it works fine (if i put hardcoded values):

```
TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0.0f, 0.0f,
        -20.0f, 120.0f);          //  new TranslateAnimation(xFrom,xTo, yFrom,yTo)
animation.setDuration(9000);  // animation duration
animation.setRepeatCount(15);  // animation repeat count
animation.setRepeatMode(2);   // repeat animation (left to right, right to left )
//animation.setFillAfter(true);
show_image.startAnimation(animation);  // start animation
```

But main problem that I can't get correct value of image height to set animation moving ranges.

How should I get this to start animation that moves up/down only in imageView ranges?

Comment: `I've got RelativeLayout, that has 3 Relative Relayouts inside` ... don't

Comment: why? I have sliding menu, so it has 3 components  that must be aligned separately. And I don't think that there is problem.

Comment: I've got your idea. ImageView then will be right size (that was downloaded), but then my sliding menu bar component will be not same size (as I need to be). So it's not a solution :/

Comment: Due to the way the layout of RelativeLayouts work, having nested RelativeLayouts causes lots of re-layouts, and probably isn't the most efficient way.

Comment: Well. I can change layout that is inside to any type of layout that could center my image. So it might be LinearLayout inside, if it will help to solve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, i did what i needed - scaled imageView to fit layout width and started animation to move up/down and show image in this way.

Firstly, xml looks like this. image_layout is child layout at is placed inside other RelativeLayout. It has fixed height (200dp)

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/image_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/tvshow_imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:transformPivotX="0dp"
        android:transformPivotY="0dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/dummy"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Code looks like this:

```
    UrlImageViewHelper.setUrlDrawable(show_image, url, R.drawable.dummy, new UrlImageViewCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onLoaded(ImageView imageView, Bitmap loadedBitmap,
                             String url, boolean loadedFromCache) {
            if (!url.equalsIgnoreCase(imageURL)) { 
                show_image.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                int imageViewWidth = dpToPx(imageRelativeLayout.getWidth());
                int imageViewHeight = dpToPx(imageRelativeLayout.getHeight());

                float ratioWidth = (float) imageViewWidth / loadedBitmap.getWidth();
                float animationBounds = loadedBitmap.getHeight() * ratioWidth - imageViewHeight;
                imageView.setScaleX(ratioWidth);
                imageView.setScaleY((ratioWidth));
                if (animationBounds > 0)
                    showImageAnimation(animationBounds);

            }
        }
    });
```

So I'm downloading image and if download is successful, i scale it to fit and start animation (moving up and down). If download is not successful I show dummy image that I have in drawables. Also it is needed to have dpToPx method to calculate scale ratio.

```
private int dpToPx(int value) {
    Resources r = InformationFragment.this.getResources();
    return (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(
            TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
            value,
            r.getDisplayMetrics()
    );
}
```

And last method to show animation (need fix on animation speed formula):

```
private void showImageAnimation(float animationBounds) {
    TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0.0f, 0.0f,
            0.0f, -animationBounds);
    animation.setDuration((int)animationBounds/20*1000);
    animation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
    animation.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);     
    show_image.startAnimation(animation);
}
```